# How to cite a youtube comment [in bibtex]

Tags: bibtex, citing

I was looking online for how to cite a youtube comment and I found [this WikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Cite-YouTube-in-APA) for how to cite a youtube comment in APA. However, I don't know how to do this in general for BibTeX. I don't really know what fields to fill out. Is it important to include the video it comes from? I couldn't find a way to link to the comment itself so I wouldn't know what link to include (the link to the original video?)

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.se! You could use the same approach as when citing a blog post, as recommended [here](https://blogs.plos.org/mfenner/2011/07/21/how-to-formally-cite-a-blog-post/).

Comment: I've added a few examples below in case you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to this could be to use the [`@misc`](http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/help/fieldsAndEntryTypes.php#misc) entry type like so:

```
@misc{youtubeComment2018,
    author = {Name of comment Author},
    title = {Title of Youtube video},
    journal = {Youtube},
    type = {Youtube Comment},
    year = {2018},
    howpublished = {\url{url to youtube video}},
    note = {In comment section, accessed on 2018/12/04}
}
```

here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{youtubeComment2018,
    author = {CheckMyPlaylist},
    title = {5 Scientists with Ideas That Nobody Believed ... Who Were Right},
    journal = {Youtube---SciShow},
    type = {Youtube Comment},
    year = {2018},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_zFyXWxxMA}},
    note = {In comment section, accessed~2018-12-04}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
From the comment on Youtube~\cite{youtubeComment2018}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

*Update, since I didn't use `{}` on capitalized letters, they will be in lowercase on the output:*

[image: apa using bibtex]

note that no fields are actually required for bibtex to work, so you can use any of the above as you see fit.

if you use [BibLATEX](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en), you can use the entry type [`@online`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex#Reference_guide):

```
@online{ytcomment2018,
    author = {name of author},
    title = {Video title},
    year  = {2018},
    url   = {add url to video here},
    urldate = {2018-12-04}
}
```

and one more MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
@online{ytcomment2018,
    author = {CheckMyPlaylist},
    title = {5 {S}cientists with {I}deas {T}hat {N}obody {B}elieved \ldots {W}ho {W}ere {R}ight},
    titleaddon = {{C}omment on video published by the {S}ci{S}how {Y}outube {C}hannel},
    year  = {2018},
    url   = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_zFyXWxxMA},
    urldate = {2018-12-04}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\begin{document}
From the comment on Youtube~\cite{ytcomment2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

*note the use of `{}` on capitalized letters.*

which will output:

[image: apa using biblatex]

with BibLATEX, you can also use optional fields such as `subtitle`, `titleaddon` or `language` as you see fit.

Comment: Should I be using BibLATEX? Is that more standard?

Comment: BibLaTeX has more entry types, my recommendation is anecdotal but I've found it to be more robust.

Comment: `biblatex-apa` as loaded by `style=apa` implements a full APA style, `apalike` on the other hand only implements a style 'like APA'. So maybe `style=authoryear` would also work. I strongly recommend *not* protecting all words in titles with `{}`: If you don't like the fact that APA requires sentence casing, turn that off with `\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}`. Anyway, I'd prefer `title = {5 {Scientists} with {Ideas}...}` over `title = {5 {S}cientists with {I}deas...}` for kerning reasons.